# How can I read value in square brackets of appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, appsettings

I have appsettings.json with code:

```
"Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "/home/www-data/aissubject/storage/logs/log-{Date}.txt"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

How can I read value of "pathFormat" key?

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is a JSON array. How you *access* that varies depending on what you're doing, but I'm assuming that since you're asking this, you're trying to get it directly out of `IConfiguration`, rather than using the options pattern (as you likely should be).

`IConfiguration` is basically a dictionary. In order to create the keys of that dictionary from something like JSON, the JSON is "flattened" using certain conventions. Each level will be separated by a colon. Arrays will be flattened by adding a colon-delimited component containing the index. In other words, to get at `pathFormat` in this particular example, you'd need:

```
Configuration["Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:pathFormat"]
```

Where the `0` portion denotes that you're getting the first item in the array. Again, it's much better and more appropriate to use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to map the configuration values onto an actual object, which would let you actually access this as an array rather than a magic string like this.

Comment: I tried to use many variants. This works. I understood. Thank you very much.